# sql registros = 0

Tags: sql, group-by

quero mostrar qtos clientes eu tenho em cada cidade
esse sql funciona

mas por exemplo, se em são paulo eu não tiver nenhum cliente cadastro, ele simplesmente oculta a cidade do meu relatorio
como eu faço para qdo tiver zero clientes ele mostrar: São Paulo   0

```
SELECT count(*) as total, municipio.nome FROM clientes 
inner join municipio on clientes.codmunicipio = municipio.codigo
group by codmunicipio
```

Comment: `inner join` só traz as linhas existentes em ambas as tabelas, para isso precisa fazer um join que traga tudo de municipio, ainda que não tenha linhas em clientes, pode usar um `right join`. Isso vai trazer null, dai pode converter para zero, dependendo do banco de dados que estiver usando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--eu faço este artifício , dados que "não existem"
--se aplica melhor a sqls mais complicadas 
--neste caso um outer join resolve também

```
select sum(total) total,nome 
from   (SELECT count(*) as total, municipio.nome 
        FROM clientes 
        inner join municipio on clientes.codmunicipio = municipio.codigo
        group by codmunicipio
        union all
        SELECT 0 as total, m2.nome FROM municipio m2) virtual 
group by nome
```

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar o `COALESCE`

```
SELECT COALESCE(count(*), 0) as total, municipio.nome FROM clientes 
right join municipio on clientes.codmunicipio = municipio.codigo
group by codmunicipio
```

Comment: teria de ir de municipios para clientes com outer join