# Como eu faço um select entre duas datas e traga na consulta o valor 0 nas datas que não existirem?

Tags: mysql, query, select

Exemplo
`select data, valor from tabela WHERE data BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-10'`.
Eu preciso que quando não exista o dia 5, por exemplo, a consulta me retorne as 10 datas e no dia 5 o valor seja igual a zero.

```html
SELECT DATA, VALOR FROM `TABELA` WHERE data BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-04-10' ORDER BY DATA ASC
```

Comment: vc não disse o BD , o que eu faço nestes casos (Oracle é simples) faço uma sequencia de datas com valores zerados e faço a soma veja se ajuda https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/522521-for%C3%A7ar-select-trazer-linha-mesmo-que-sem-valor/ https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/446579/sql-registros-0/446717#446717

Comment: Meu bd é o phpmyadmin

Comment: Mysql  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105018/generating-a-series-of-dates    https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224182/generate-dates-between-date-ranges-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para isso será necessário fazer um JOIN entre os seus dados e uma "tabela" com todas as datas. Para que não seja necessário criar essa tabela, pode-se usar CTE. Para ter o valor 0 onde não existir valor, pode-se usar o `COALESCE`. Assim, a sua query ficaria algo como

```sql
WITH recursive dias AS (
  select '2020-04-01' as data
  union all
  select data + interval 1 day
  from dias
  where data < '2020-04-10')
SELECT dias.data, COALESCE(valor, 0)
FROM dias
LEFT JOIN tabela on dias.data = tabela.data
ORDER BY dias.data ASC
```

É possível testar este exemplo no fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ctZk4hTXnGJt8TFwm32bER/2.

Comment: tvdias, eu agradeço imensamente, não só por ter resolvido meu problema, mas por ter dedicado seu tempo para me ajudar!

Comment: E também você me apresentou uma nova ferramenta, que até então eu desconhecia.