# SQL - Preciso retornar meses com valores zerados, mesmo que não tenha resultado

Tags: sql

Preciso retornar as linhas de uma consulta, mesmo que não tenha valor.
Essa tabela tem mais de status e preciso que retorne todos os status com os respectivos meses e ano escolhidos, mas com a quantidade zerada.

**Segue query:**

```
SELECT count(*) as total_pedidos, 
year(p.data) as ano, 
month(p.data) as mes, 
p.status as status 
 FROM pedido as p                                        
 LEFT JOIN relacao as r ON r.id = p.relacao_id                                                          
WHERE
p.data between '2020-01-01 00:00' and '2020-05-01 23:59' 
and p.status in ('AGENDADO')                                 
GROUP BY
month(p.data),
YEAR(p.data),
p.status
```

**Segue resultado atual:**

```
total_pedidos | ano     |     mes  | status
-------------------------------------------------------------------
36            | 2020    |      4   | AGENDADO
```

**Preciso que retorne:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
total_pedidos | ano     |     mes   | status
-------------------------------------------------------------------
0             | 2020    |      1    | AGENDADO
0             | 2020    |      2    | AGENDADO
0             | 2020    |      3    | AGENDADO
36            | 2020    |      4    | AGENDADO
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Crie uma tabela auxiliar de meses e faça um LEFT OUTER JOIN com sua query acima utilizando `COALESCE(total_pedidos, 0)`. Caso esteja utilizando o PostgreSQL então você pode utilizar: `SELECT * FROM generate_series('2020-01-01 00:00'::timestamp, '2020-05-01 23:59', '1 month');`.

Comment: Amigo, fiz a seguinte querye e está retornando apenas uma linha ainda :(

Comment: create table #tempMeses (id int identity(1,1), mes varchar(250),)
 insert into #tempMeses select 'Janeiro'
 insert into #tempMeses select 'Fevereiro'
 insert into #tempMeses select 'Março'
 insert into #tempMeses select 'Abril'
 insert into #tempMeses select 'Maio'
 insert into #tempMeses select 'Junho'
 insert into #tempMeses select 'Julho'
 insert into #tempMeses select 'Agosto'
 insert into #tempMeses select 'Setembro'
 insert into #tempMeses select 'Outubro'
 insert into #tempMeses select 'Novembro'
 insert into #tempMeses select 'Dezembro'

 continua...

Comment: Como você colocou sua tabela #tempMeses do lado direito do JOIN então utilie `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Amigo,  continua trazendo apenas uma linha.

Comment: Lembre-se de que num OUTER JOIN os campos que não tem correspondente na outra tabela ficam com NULL naquela linha. Tente trocar month(p.data_inspecao) por #tempMeses.id na lista de campos do SELECT.

Comment: Não sei o que acontece, mesmo após colocar #tempMeses.id, continua aparecendo apenas uma linha. Será que tenho que alterar algo mais ou tem outro esquema?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/446579/sql-registros-0

Comment: Pessoal, ainda não deu certo.

Comment: Poste a query que não está apresentando o resultado desejado.

Comment: Amigo anônimo, após as suas recomendações a query ficou dessa forma: 
SELECT COALESCE(count(*) , 0) as total_pedidos, 
year(p.data) as ano, 
month(p.data) as mes, 
p.status as status 
 FROM pedido as p             
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN #tempMeses ON #tempMeses.id = month(p.data) 
 LEFT JOIN relacao as r ON r.id = p.relacao_id                                                          
WHERE
p.data between '2020-01-01 00:00' and '2020-05-01 23:59' 
and p.status in ('AGENDADO')                                 
GROUP BY
month(p.data),
YEAR(p.data),
p.status

Comment: O que eu sugeri foi: 
`SELECT COALESCE(count(*) , 0) as total_pedidos, year(p.data) as ano, #tempMeses.id as mes, p.status as status 
FROM pedido as p RIGHT OUTER JOIN #tempMeses ON #tempMeses.id = month(p.data) 
WHERE p.data between '2020-01-01 00:00' and '2020-05-01 23:59' and p.status in ('AGENDADO') 
GROUP BY #tempMeses.id, YEAR(p.data), p.status`. Encerrando esta discussão.

Comment: Muito obrigado a todos que me ajudaram, abraços!